# How do I get storage size and used storage in google apps API

Tags: gmail, google-api, google-admin-sdk

I am trying to retrieve the size of users email boxes for my Google apps domain but I am having a hard time finding this in the APIs from Google.  Does anyone know where this is?  I see that they can do it in the gapps console but can not find where this is.

I am using the gapps .net client so if it is in there that would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

You can get [Gmail quota and usage](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/usage-ref-appendix-a/users-gmail) numbers for a user using the new [Admin SDK Reports API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/get-start/getting-started) calls.

Comment: Does that serve google apps too?  I was a bit confused what was consumer and what was for apps.

Comment: Admin SDK is only for Google Apps, it has nothing to do with consumer accounts.

Comment: Huh interesting... I can't seem to find the USER keys per a google apps account, I am familiar with the provisioning API though.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/reports/v1/reports.activities.list First field is a userkey.  Also... I can't see what actually gives you the storage space you are using and what the limit is.

Comment: you should be using https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/reports/v1/reports.userUsageReport.get the userKey can be the user's primary SMTP email address.